# Show midnight as 00:00 instead of 24:00 in timeGridWeek and timeGridDay view of react fullcalendar plugin

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using `@fullcalendar/react` in my project for Calendar feature. I have used the time grid plugin provided with it for week view and day view. But when I changed it to 24-hour format it shows midnight as 24:00 whereas I want it to show 00:00. I have tried going through the entire document without much success. Can anybody help me with it?

Below is the snippet of my FullCalendar component:

```
<FullCalendar
    firstDay={1}
    editable={false}
    selectable={false}
    dayMaxEvents={true}
    selectLongPressDelay={0}
    eventLongPressDelay={0}
    selectMirror={false}
    headerToolbar={{
        start: 'prev title next',
        end: 'dayGridMonth timeGridWeek timeGridDay',
    }}
    titleFormat={{ month: 'long' }}
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
    views={{
        dayGridMonth: {},
        timeGridWeek: {
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotLabelFormat: {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                hour12: false,
            },
            dayHeaderFormat: {
                weekday: 'long',
                day: '2-digit',
            },
        },
        timeGridDay: {
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotLabelFormat: {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                hour12: false,
            },
            dayHeaderFormat: {
                weekday: 'long',
                day: '2-digit',
            },
        },
    }}
    nowIndicator={true}
/>;
```

What changes do I need to achieve this?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features is probably the correct route for this request, realistically. Unless you want to get into making custom views yourself.

Comment: I just want to know if there is an existing feature for achieving this. If there is no such feature at present, is there any workaround to do this.

Comment: `I just want to know if there is an existing feature`...well I think the answer to that was pretty clearly implied by the fact I pointed you to the page to request features. And as for workarounds- again I mentioned it: you would likely need to start making a custom view. Or you might even need to mess with the date formatting functions. I don't think there is anything you can do to fix it without one of those approaches.